# How to replace a string having special characters in xml file by unix commands

Tags: xml, unix, sed

I need to replace the below string with null . Its basically an xml file and i want to omit the xmnls part using unix commands.

`xmlns:stl="http://www.xxx.yy/1234/stl-1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"`

I have tried using the below commands :

```
perl -pi -e "s+xmlns:stl="http://www.xxx.yy/1234/stl-1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"++" filename.xml

sed 's+xmlns:stl="http://www.xxx.yy/1234/stl-1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"++' filename.xml
```

Didnt work out well. :(
Does the experts have any idea on how this should be handled.

PS: Its a continuous line having tags after the string 
 value `xmlns:stl="http://www.xxx.yy/1234/stl-1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"`. So cannot delete the line

Comment: add a complete sample input line and output you get with the command you tried... also, probably xml parsers like xmlstarlet would be better choice than using regex

Comment: To edit your file in place, try the `-i` flag: `sed -i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sed` line works reasonably well, but:

1. To edit the file in place instead of writing the result to stdout, use `sed -i`.
2. To make it predictable, you need to escape regex special characters with `\`, like this:

   ```
   sed -i 's+xmlns:stl="http://www\.xxx\.yy/1234/stl-1\.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www\.w3\.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"++' filename.xml
   ```